# Spring integration inbound-gateway Fire an event when queue is empty

Tags: routes, jms, spring-integration

I'm a newbie around but I'll try to be consice.

```
{INPUT QUEUE}->[INBOUND-GATEWAY-1]-->[ROUTER]----------->(ACTIVATOR)<---------------
                                        \                                          /
                                         \-->{HOLD QUEUE}--->[INBOUND-GATEWAY-2]--^
```

I'm having an scenario in which I have to dynamically change routing conditions in a flow like the former. Messages comming from a queue are sent to an activator to be processed, or another queue to be put on hold. At certain time, I have to close INBOUND-GATEWAY-1 so no new messages come into the flow, and open INBOUND-GATEWAY-2 to let all messages from HOLD QUEUE be processed. Once all messages from HOLD QUEUE were been consumed, both gateways must me closed/opened as they were before. The thing here is how could I know when HOLD QUEUE is empty so I could trigger a method in which gateway-1 could be started?

I'd be grateful if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging and reading, finally I came to a solution for this issue. An inbound-gateway is a JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint, based in two inner components, a MessageListenerContainer and a MessageListener. MessageListenerContainer is the one in charge at scheduling MessageListener behaviour so, overriding the noMessageReceived and messageReceived, and adding some attributes to control the desired behaviour, I could be able to do the "magic".

My MessageListenerContainer implementation got like this.

```java
public class ControlMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer{

    private JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint mainInputGateway;

    private long timeOut;

    private long lastTimeReceived;  

    public PassControlMessageListenerContainer() {
        this.setAutoStartup(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws JmsException {
        /*When the container is started the lastTimeReceived is set to actial time*/
        lastTimeReceived = (new Date()).getTime();
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void noMessageReceived(Object invoker, Session session) {
        long actualTime = (new Date()).getTime();

        if((actualTime - lastTimeReceived) >= timeOut 
                && mainInputGateway != null && !mainInputGateway.isRunning()){
            mainInputGateway.start();
        }       
        super.noMessageReceived(invoker, session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(Object invoker, Session session) {
        /*lastTimeReceived is set again to actual time at new message arrive*/
        lastTimeReceived = (new Date()).getTime();
        super.messageReceived(invoker, session);
    }
}
```

And finally, the spring bean config get like this:

```xml
<bean id="listenerContainer" 
    class="org.merol.ControlMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="mainInputGateway" ref="mainGateway" />
    <property name="destination" ref="onHoldQueue" />
    <property name="timeOut" value="10000"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" 
    class="org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener">
    <property name="requestChannel" ref="outputChannel" />
</bean>

<bean id="inboundGateway" 
    class="org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint">
    <constructor-arg name="listenerContainer" ref="listenerContainer" />
    <constructor-arg name="listener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Hope this could be helpful for someone else.

Thanks to @Nicholas for the clues.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this functionality into the inbound gateway processors. For example:

**Gateway1Processor:**

- *start()*: Start consumer off the main
  queue and process.
- *stop()*: Stop consumer.

**Gateway2Processor:**

- *start()*: Start consumer off the HOLD queue. Specify an appropriate timeout. When timeout is fired, (the HOLD queue is empty) call *stop()*.
- *stop()*: Start **Gateway1Processor** and stop this consumer.

Therefore, the operating sequence would be:

1. Start **Gateway1Processor**
2. At **a certain time**, call **Gateway1Processor.stop()** and **Gateway2Processor.start()**
3. **Gateway2Processor** will drain the HOLD queue, restart **Gateway1Processor** and then stop.
4. Go To #2.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, I think this could be implemented using a org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer
 or org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer
.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, @Nicholas. I just have a doubt about this: what's the class used by the `<jms:inbound-gateway>` tag? I mean, i supose i have to make my own implementation and/or override methods of the inbound-gateway so i could replace this 
`<jms:inbound-gateway id="cancel.book.dispatcher" 
  request-channel="receiverBookChannel" 
  request-destination="cancel.wait.book.engine" 
  auto-startup="false"/>`
with something like this
`<bean class="myImplementedGateway">
<property name="requestChannel" ref=""/>
...
</bean>`