# Pick jms message when required in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have a requirement to fetch jms message from IBM MQ. But the messages should be fetched only when required, say when a method is invoked. The picked up message need to be put to another queue in turn. That is , this scenario is for copying message from one queue to another when required.

How could I achieve this in Spring Integration.

I believe i could create a flow using inbound-channel-adapter, set to poll message at regular interval, along with outbound-channel-adapter. But with this, I could not pick the message as and when required.

Please advise.

### Question updated:

1) While searching on the web to implement the suggested solution, I stepped on the spring documentation for JmsDestinationPollingSource saying - "This source is only recommended for very low message volume".

2) Since we need for high volume environment and in need of local transaction,  I looked into the suggested JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint solution which looked like using MessageDrivenChannelAdapter. Can you please adviseas how i could proceed.

3) Also, in that case how can i detect if all messages have been read to stop the listener . Please advise

### Question updated:

I am able to invoke start and stop on DefaultMessageListener container used with MessageDrivenChannelAdapter.

Can you also please advise as how I could find when there are no messages on the queue or when the queue is empty so that I could invoke stop.

### Question updated:

Thanks Gary. Sorry for the late update.

To find when the queue becomes empty, can we override noMessageReceived method of DefaultMessageListenerContainer (inherited from AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer) and invoke stop on the DMLC. This kind of solution is given in 
   [Spring integration inbound-gateway Fire an event when queue is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024028/spring-integration-inbound-gateway-fire-an-event-when-queue-is-empty).

I thought this might be easier to implement. Please advise if it will be correct to do in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `auto-startup="false"` on the inbound channel adapter (so it won't poll).

Get a reference to its `MessageSource` (either by `@Autowire` or otherwise injecting or `context.getBean()`). The bean name is `adapterid.source` and is of type `JmsDestinationPollingSource`.

Then invoke the `receive()` method.

Or you can just wire up a `JmsDestinationPollingSource` bean yourself without using the namespace support.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Have updated the question again. Forgot to mention that I need local transaction to be enabled and that there could be high volume of messages. Can you please advise.

Comment: The comment about low volume isn't really an issue; I think it really is just pointing you towards the message driven adapter because it can be configured for concurrent threads. However, when using transactions with the polled source, the transaction is committed right after the receive, so you can't do more work in that session, you would have to use a message-driven adapter for that; any downstream `JmsTemplate` (for the same connection facory) will use the same transacted session. To stop the adapter you'd have to monitor the work and `stop()` it when messages stop flowing.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Now, I am able to invoke start and stop successfully on DefaultMessageListenerContainer assigned to MessageDrivenChannelAdapter in Spring Integration. One more issue is - I am unable to identify when the queue is empty, in order to invoke stop. Have updated the question too. Please advise.

Comment: There's nothing standard in JMS to detect an empty queue; you could use JMX to monitor the adapter's channel `sendCount` and stop it after it hasn't incremented for some period of time. Or you can add a custom interceptor to the channel to maintain a message count if you don't want to use JMX.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Sorry for the late update. To find when the queue becomes empty,  can we override noMessageReceived method of DefaultMessageListenerContainer (inherited from AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer) and invoke stop on the DMLC. This kind of solution is given in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024028/spring-integration-inbound-gateway-fire-an-event-when-queue-is-empty . I thought this might be easier to implement. Please advise if it will be correct to do in that way.

Comment: Yes, that will work too; just be sure to invoke the super method. I would recommend you actually stop the container on a different thread, though, not the container thread itself.